# Website Background on iOS - Wrong Size

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a website and I can't get the website background to appear in the correct size on iOS:
http://www.anniefouldspersonaltrainer.com

The background either shrinks really small or (if you scroll down) you can see it's misaligned.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey your website is not Responsive web designed thats why website content is not proper fit in webview.

[Read about Responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)